# QFileDialog does not open a dialog window on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, qfiledialog

I am coding up a Qt GUI (PyQt5) in Python on MacOS. I run my program using `python test.py` in terminal.

When I attempt to use a QFileDialog static method such as QFileDialog.getOpenFileName, I get the following error instead of a dialog window opening:

```
2021-10-11 12:06:48.411 python[49048:17688470] +[NSXPCSharedListener endpointForReply:withListenerName:]: an error occurred while attempting to obtain endpoint for listener 'com.apple.view-bridge': Connection interrupted
```

I am able to get around this by constantly restarting the application and trying to open the dialog until it works. It usually works after 3 - 5 restarts. This is not ideal for any future users or if there is data that needs to be saved in the application prior to restarting.

Here is a minimal reproducible example script:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QFileDialog
    )


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    """The main window of the application"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Initializes and shows the main window of the application"""

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())

        # open file button
        self.open_file_button = QPushButton(self)
        self.open_file_button.setText("Open File")
        self.open_file_button.clicked.connect(self.open_file)

        self.layout().addWidget(self.open_file_button)

        self.show()

    def open_file(self):
        file_name, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)

        if file_name:
            ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

macOS version: Catalina 10.15.1 (19B88)

Python Version: 3.8.11

PyQt5 Version: 5.15.4

PyQt5-Qt5 Version: 5.15.2

Comment: There are a few reports related to this (see [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/1858371)), and it seems it is a problem with that specific version of Catalina (which I'd say it's a bit outdated). Can you try with another version of Catalina? If that's the case, the only possible workaround is to use the `DontUseNativeDialog` option.

Comment: I've updated to Catalina 10.15.7 and I haven't encountered the issue so far. For now it seems yours is an acceptable answer for me considering how old Catalina 10.15.1 is.